# How to get a right "densityplot" in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, density-plot

I have a dataframe in which I have Recall values for 2 different groups of data. I have made a density plot using below code but I am confused about how it looks. For one group (GE in this case) the recall is very high (always 1), in the plot I anticipate a sharp and comparatively higher peak (w.r.t. Epi group) at x-axis=1 while this is not the case in the output graph (see attached picture).

Command I used:

```
ggplot(epiGE, aes(x=Rec)) + geom_density(aes(group=Class, colour=Class, fill=Class), alpha=0.3) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image: DensityPlot]

I have also tried ggplot2 histogram but there as well at x-axis=1 I don't get the right distribution of `GE` group, as the barplot shows that values in `Epi` group having `Recall=1` are more as compared to `GE` group.

```
ggplot(epiGE, aes(x=Rec)) + geom_histogram(aes(group=Class, colour=Class, fill=Class), alpha=0.3) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image: BarPlot]

Can somebody please guide me what I am doing wrong here?? Thank you.

Here is my data dput:

```
> dput(epiGE)
structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Epi", "GE"), class = "factor"), 
    Rec = c(1, 1, 0.928571428571429, 1, 1, 1, 0.625, 1, 0.935897435897436, 
    1, 0.911764705882353, 1, 0.790697674418605, 1, 0.891891891891892, 
    1, 1, 1, 0.98019801980198, 1, 0.949367088607595, 1, 0.877551020408163, 
    1, 0.944444444444444, 1, 1, 1, 0.955445544554455, 1, 0.5, 
    1, 0.170731707317073, 1, 0.513513513513513, 1, 0, 1, 0.9, 
    1, 0.875, 1, 0.884615384615385, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.9, 1)), .Names = c("Class", 
"Rec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the bandwidth of smoothing. You can use the `adjust` argument to adjust the bandwidth. Here is an example.

```
ggplot(epiGE, aes(x=Rec)) + 
  geom_density(aes(group=Class, colour=Class, fill=Class), alpha=0.3, adjust = 1/10) + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Set `adjust` to `1/10` means using `1/10` of the default bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for taking out the time to try. I have already tried this parameter but still if you see the plot then red peak (representing Epi group) is above the green peak (representing the GE group) which I interperate as Epi class has more data points having Recall=1 as compared to GE class and this is not the case here (if you see the recall values for both classes).

Comment: There are only 7 or 8 values belonging to class Epi which has Recall in range of 0.8 to 1 while all the values in GE class has a Recall = 1 so in this case the height of peak representing GE values should be higher as compared to height of peak (in region 0.9 - 1) representing Epi values. But what we see in plot is opposite of it.

Comment: How about `adjust = 1/50`? I feel like density plot may not be the most suitable plot to achieve what you want.

Comment: At that high adjust the peaks are so narrow that I cannot see how many points from Epi group also have Rec=1. Even barplot is not helping here, if you see the figure posted in the question. Principally in that figure the red bar should be at bottom, showing that 4 or 5 datapoints were having Rec=1 for Epi Class but 24 were having Rec=1 for GE class that's why green bar is so high. But even there the red bar is frustratingly on top.